# Learning jQuery - triggerHandler issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a lot of success in developing a bookmarklet to fill in a complex form with default values.  All of the text/textarea fields are now saving correctly with the following jQuery code:

```
$("#frm_PatientGoals").val("To get stronger.").triggerHandler('focus');
```

Unfortunately, if the field in question is a checkbox or radio button adding the .triggerHandler doesn't get the job done.  Here is an example of one of those elements:

```
$('#frm_hsResWeak').prop('checked', true);
```

This page will correctly store the .val data provided thanks to the .triggerHandler but the same is not true for the .prop for the checkboxes of which there are numerous that I would like to set.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.  I'm definitely a JS and jQuery noob, but would like to learn more.

Comment: why would you need to `focus` on the input if you just want to set its value?

Comment: Not certain what Question is? Are you expecting `$('#frm_hsResWeak').prop('checked', true);` to invoke `focus` event? And call `.triggerHandler`?

Comment: When I run the bookmarklet it does indeed change the status of the checkbox as desired.  The problem is when I click save on the form, this checkbox status is NOT saved in the form.  I think I missed that in the initial description.  Before including the .triggerHandler('focus'), the text fields also did not save when clicking the save button.